# Help with Reduction of Order - xy" = 2y'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this second order EDO here xy''= 2y' and I need to reduce this to a first order EDO and solve it. My problem is that I don't have any solution of this equation to make this reduction. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the RHS $2y$ or $2y'$?

Comment: 2y', sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $y_1=c\neq 0$ is a solution. For another one, we can just use the reduction of order formula: $$y_2={y_1}\int\left(\frac{1}{y_1^2}\exp(-\int P(x)dx)\right)dx$$ where $P(x)=\frac{-2}{x}$.

Comment: I understand the formula, but I don't know what I do with the result. The result is a solution, right? And the y1, I keep it in the formula or I replace it for a constant?

Answer (score 0):

In the second form you can use that 
$$
(x^{-2}y')'=x^{-2}y''-2x^{-3}y'=0
$$